# Responsive embed won't show

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap v 3.3 for building my webpage and I want to implement a video. I have copied the code from www.getbootstrap.com into my `.html` file, but It doesn't show the video, It just makes a lot of free space on the webpage.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="row-fluid">  
      <div class="col-sm-3">
         <h3>Co to vlastně je?</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-9">
         <p class="odstavec"> Webové stránky nás v životě doprovází již od roku 1991, kdy zaměstnanec Evropské organizace pro jaderný výzkum sir Tim Berners-Lee vypustil na web vůbec první internetovou stránku. Jejím cílem bylo popsat princip WWW a podpořit rozvoj nové technologie. </p> 
         <p class="odstavec"> Od té doby se technologie posunula výrazně dopředu. Webové stránky jsou v současnosti pro většinu lidí nezbytnou součástí v životě. S nástupem chytrých telefonů, tabletů a jiných zařízení však přišla na řadu další důležitá otázka. Jak zařídit, aby byly webové stránky optimalizovány pro výše zmíněné zařízení s různou velikostí displeje, na kterých se mají zobrazit. </p>
         <p class="odstavec"> S termínem „responzivní webový design“ přišel poprvé v roce 2010 Ethan Marcotte. Responzivním designem nazval takový návrh webové stránky, jenž bude optimalizován pro všechny druhy zařízení. Abych to shrnul, responzivní stránka je tedy taková stránka, která své zobrazení přizpůsobí velikosti zobrazovací plochy zařízení, z kterého na web uživatel přistupuje. </p>
      </div> 

      <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
          <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wjsw--Oad6M"></iframe>
      </div>

    </div>  
   </div>     
</div> <!-- End row-fluid-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is happening is because of a restriction on Youtube's side. Google and all its products do the same thing.

They restrict access to its content when requested through `iframes`. If you check the console when running the page you will probably see something like this:

> Refused to display 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wjsw--Oad6M' in a
>   frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

These restrictions are usually for security reasons or to stop people embedding their content on a website. They have restricted the url being called, it can only be called from the origin domain if used inside an `iframe`. You can see more information about it here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

To embed your video on the page you should use the proper embed code Youtube gives on the video page. So in your case:

`<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/wjsw--Oad6M" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Example here : http://jsfiddle.net/zxjmw5j4/1/

Comment: You were right with the console, there is the exact sentence. But if i replace my iframe with the one you have provided, it still doesn't show the video. And another thing is, will it still be responsive? @haxtbh

Comment: I have updated the answer with a jsFiddle example to show you it working. Some of your HTML was incorrect as there were a few too many `</div>` tags.

Comment: Are you able to see it directly via the youtube link? Use a different youtube link to see if it makes a difference. Some videos are blocked depending on location etc.

Comment: I fixed the problem. I had to put it into the row and column and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

For the first, you have several extra `</div>`, remove them. And try to use another video, i`ve tried

```html
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/jDRTghGZ7XU"></iframe>
</div>
```

and it work fine for me.

Comment: Thats is not working for the reason discussed above.